# Adding Image file to user in ASP .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is dring me nuts! I have a web app i have created using ASP .net core2. I have a registration page that allows a user to select an image file and this is working. I use this is my Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Face Image")]
Public IFormFile UserImageFile { get; set; }
```

In my AccountController class I have

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var imageBytes = GetByteArrayFromImage(model.UserImageFile);
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, UserImage = imageBytes};
            user.UserImage = imageBytes;
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

This all seems to work. If I debug and look at the user, I can see that UserImage has a byte array. All seems ok BUT the field in the database isnt getting the value. Is there a step I have to add somewhere that is hidden to set this value on the database?

Comment: If you are facing that issue (You are not experienced on that), using a BLOB will probably be a better approach. You'll avoid many complications. If you still want to use that, tell us what is your column type? Is it SQLServer?

Comment: The table is AspNetUsers and I have tried column type Image and now var binary max 
 [UserImage]            VARBINARY (MAX)    NULL

Comment: will varbinary(Max) take a byte array?

Comment: got it for that part..I hadnt added {get; set;} doh! will re test

Answer (score 1):

ok so I was so very close to having it right! All I was missing was the `{get; set;}`! for my new field definition in ApplicationUser. now it works perfect